# Pybrain not working with Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, pybrain

I installed Python 3.6.1. And then installed pybrain using git (See Screen Shot). Then when I use`import pybrain`it works but afterwards when I use`from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork`it gives me error that:  `Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.`

```
>>> import pybrain

>>> from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
File "C:\Users\davm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools\shortcuts.py", line 14
    except ImportError, e:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

>>> from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
File "C:\Users\davm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pybrain\structure\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from connections.__init__ import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connections'
```

Why is it doing like this? Kindly help me out here. Thanks

EDIT: Excluded screen shots. Added everything in post as per request.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors — [edit] your post and add the error as a text.

Comment: Added error as text now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update: I was able to resolve the issue by un-installing python, then installing python 3.6.2 (64 bit), using pip3 (`pip3 install pybrain`) I was able to install the latest version of pybrain which worked flawlessly. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out when I was fairly new to python. Love this community!!

Answer (score 2):

`except ImportError, e` is Python 2 syntax and you've tried to run the code with Python 3. Install the latest version — the code seems to be fixed in git (it's `except ImportError as e` now, so it's suitable for both Python 2.7 and Python 3).

Comment: Latest version of what?

Comment: Latest version of PyBrain.

Comment: I have searched everywhere. And wasn't able to find the latest version of PyBrain? Can you give me the link?